# jquery - who is my parent listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".cblClaimSources").on('click', ':checkbox', function (){
    alert('im : '+ $(this).attr('id') + ' and my Parent listener is '+ ?????);
});
```

is it possible for the `insider  $(this)` to know who is its listener parent ? [`$(".cblClaimSources")`] ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using jQuery 1.7:

```
$(".cblClaimSources").on('click', ':checkbox', function (e) {
  var parentListener = e.delegateTarget;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mHXMq/3/